# Why Windows Service stops for no reason? using C#.net

Tags: c#, windows-services

My windows service built using C#.net

It is simply calling another software using command line.

calling the software was done and 100% sure it is working from normal forms app.

In my case when I start the service it starts fine, runs a timer and within this timer run the command line.

For some reason I could not find why the service stopps by its own after the 2nd call to the timer.

I traced the problem and I could not find the reason why it stops and how to fix it.

I seimplified the service to call a "PING" command. still stops the service.

Here is my code and appreciate if someone can tell me what is the problem and how to fix it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Timers;

namespace cProcessor
{
    public partial class cProcessorSrv : ServiceBase
    {

        EventLog eventLog1;

        public cProcessorSrv()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("cPr"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "cPr", "cPrLog");
            }
            eventLog1.Source = "cPr";
            eventLog1.Log = "cPrLog";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("OnStart");
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.Interval = 15 * 1000;
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
                timer.Start();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("Exception : " + ex.ToString());

            }
        }

        public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {

            try
            { 

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("OnTimer");
            string command = "ping yahoo.com";
            string workingFolder = @"c:\";
            var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; ;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingFolder;

            var process = Process.Start(processInfo);


            process.OutputDataReceived += (object snd, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
            {

                if (e.Data.Contains("INFO FileTreeXmiWriter") || e.Data.Contains("INFO FileTreeReader") || e.Data.Contains("error"))
                {
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("output>>" + e.Data);
                }
            };


            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (object snd, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("error>>" + e.Data);
            };
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit();

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("ExitCode: " + process.ExitCode.ToString());
            process.Close();

                /* */
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("Exception :" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Here is the Log results (just 3 information)

```
OnStart 
OnTimer 
error>>
```

Comment: @00110001 as you can see there is logging.. the try catch was just deleted to simplify the code.. anyway no expections were catched.. been working on this problem for 3 days now. i tried every possible solution.

Comment: Ill take your word on that. Have you checked for any errors in event viewer? Did you log on stop? is that entire method covered with a try catch ?

Comment: If you run this program in a console app with a timer does it work without issues?

Comment: Also why are you using `Process.Start` to ping, why not just use the Ping class ? or is that just for testing

Comment: @00110001 I added Log results and Exceptions to the code Results included.. simple service.. I should mention I am using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: @00110001 I use Ping to simplify the problem.. the actual command is executing a software that I built by the company. so PING here just to show the problem

Comment: If you comment out all the timer event code, does it still stop?

Comment: @00110001 yes. if the timer is deleted the service works but does nothing

Comment: When I run the code, it crashes on `e.Data.Contains("INFO FileTreeXmiWriter")` because `e.Data` is null.  Does the problem still happen if you remove that entire IF statement?

Comment: @TawabWakil compilation error? or run-time error ?

Comment: Runtime error...

Comment: @TawabWakil i does not give me any error  !! does the service stop if you remove the if statement?

Comment: Looking in the Services panel, the service does not stop with or without the IF statement. But it crashes the debugger with the IF statement there. Could be a separate problem if it makes no difference for you.

Comment: @TawabWakil i think that could be the issue, I will check that.. It does not crash on my computer which is weird.. I will check the IF statement.. Thanks

Comment: @TawabWakil I think that was it.. I added try catch in that are and cought the error.. Thanks.. if you put this as an answer I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged the Windows Service code [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-the-onstart-method?view=vs-2019) and found that it crashed on `e.Data.Contains("INFO FileTreeXmiWriter")` because `e.Data` is null.  A solution would be to add a null check before running the IF statement.